# Can I multiply equations of a system of equations by a function without affecting the result?

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a system of equations as the following:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
f_1(x,y)=0\\
\frac{f_2(x,y)}{g_1(x)}=0\\
f_3(x,y)=0\\
\frac{f_4(x,y)}{g_2(x)}=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

where $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ are functions that contain trigonometric functions like $\cos x$ or $\cos^2 x$.

I know that I could multiply each line by a different scalar without affecting the solution. However, how will the solution be affected if I multiply the second line by $g_1(x)$ and the third line by $g_2(x)$ in order to eliminate these terms from the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - yes, if you're careful.

Longer answer:

A fraction is $0$ if and only if its numerator is $0$, so you can multiply your fractions by the functions in their denominators as long as those denominators are not $0$. When the functions in the denominator are $0$ the fractions are ambiguous - they may make sense if the numerator vanishes too in such a way as to cause the fraction to have a limit.

Comment: So in my case, I could eliminate the denominators as long as my solutions of $x$ stay away from $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$? (in the case where $g_1(x)=\cos x$ for example)